# Grouping radio buttons together with a containing element?

Tags: html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

The standard way to group radio buttons together is to assign each one a `name` attribute, and set each one in a certain group to the same "group name" like so:

```
<p>
    Group 1:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="val1">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="val2">
</p>
<p>
    Group 2:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="val3">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="val4">
</p>
```

However, having to come up with a different "group name" is a real pain when you're developing some partial code for web pages that could be used multiple times on the page.  It would be much nicer if you could instead group the radio buttons together with a surrounding element, something like this:

```
<p>
    Group 1:<br>
    <radiogroup>
        <input type="radio" value="val1">
        <input type="radio" value="val2">
    </radiogroup>
</p>
<p>
    Group 2:<br>
    <radiogroup>
        <input type="radio" value="val3">
        <input type="radio" value="val4">
    </radiogroup>
</p>
```

Is something like this possible?  Otherwise if my partial code is included twice on a page, the 2 instances of the first 2 `input`s will all be included in the same group, and the 2 instances of the second 2 `input`s will all be included in the same group.  What I want, though, is 4 groups; 2 groups per partial include.

Comment: If the elements have the same name, how do you think form processing is going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  What I ended up doing in the end was generating a new GUID for each partial and appending it to the `name` attribute of the radio buttons in that partial.

Answer (score 0):

I used the span attribute with an ID to group lists of radio buttons together.